# iTMSTransporter upload ipa to iTunes Connect Success but choose in TestFlight Failed

Tags: testflight, ipa, itmstransporter

As I see the link [upload ipa to testflight](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/#/apdA17fcd7d1)，then refer the example,

```
/usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter \
-m upload -jwt ex**** \
-asc_provider Apple \
-v eXtreme \
-assetFile /Users/jappleseed/Downloads/MyApp.ipa \
-distribution DeveloperId \
-primaryBundleId com.apple.contentdelivery.theFruitStand
```

but I got the error message, why it happened?

> ERROR: The '-assetFile' option cannot specify a file with an extension of '.ipa' when -distribution is set to 'DeveloperId'.

then I try this command, make the .ipa to .zip,

```
 /usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter \
-m upload -jwt ex**** \
-asc_provider Apple \
-v eXtreme \
-assetFile /Users/jappleseed/Downloads/MyApp.zip \
-distribution DeveloperId \
-primaryBundleId com.apple.contentdelivery.theFruitStand
```

then it show success, but I can not found the ipa in iTunes Connect, as iTunes Connect not showing my uploaded IPA.

> Package Summary:
>
> 1 packages were uploaded successfully.

Face this situation, then I try this command again, and `upload.itmsp` contains `[metadata.xml, Myapp.ipa]`.

```
/usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter \
-m upload -jwt ex**** \
-asc_provider Apple \
-v eXtreme \
-f /Users/jappleseed/Downloads/upload.itmsp/ \
-distribution DeveloperId \
-primaryBundleId com.apple.contentdelivery.theFruitStand
```

it also told me success message, and I can see the build version in iTunes connect, but I can not choose the version in TestFlight, then I can not do more.

> 1 packages were uploaded successfully:
>
> /Users/jappleseed/Downloads/upload.itmsp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use username/password authentication (-m username -p yourpassword) instead of JWT. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: yes, I had found it work for me, just not add the comment, but thanks again.